# SVG: show/hide text or textArea on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I'm using `clipPath` to apply different "masking" effects to images on a page.

Each image will have a caption of variable length. Upon hovering over the image, I want to show the caption on top of the image and on mouseout, I want to hide the caption. Because of the varying caption length, I need the text to wrap appropriately, so that the text doesn't go outside the image.

I've experimented with using `foreignObject` and `textArea`, but I couldn't seem to get the hover effect working properly.

I also attempted to use plain HTML (specifically, a paragraph tag) and absolute positioning + `z-index` to position the text, but the text size didn't scale with the image's size accordingly (because it wasn't part of the SVG).

I'm using jQuery in this project, so if a JS solution is needed, jQuery is available.

Here's the HTML that I'm working with (and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXW6C/) if needed):

```
<div class="featured-image" id="featured-image-one">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="ellipse">
        <ellipse fill="#ff0000" cx="50" cy="35.5" rx="49.5" ry="35" />
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="hexagon">
        <polygon points="25, 0  75, 0 100, 43.30127018922193 75, 86.60254037844386  25, 86.60254037844386  0, 43.30127018922193"/>
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="rectangle">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="70"></rect>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <image preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg/800px-Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg" id="clippy" clip-path="url(#hexagon)" />
      <foreignObject x="10" y="30" width="100" height="100" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
          <p style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 5px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </body>
      </foreignObject>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:  http://jsfiddle.net/LgAjd/4/

Basically I just added an `id` to your foreignObject and styled its `display` to be `none`, so it's invisible by default, and then used jQuery event bindings to handle the hover condition.

Javascript code:

```
$hoverText = $('#hoverText');
$('body').on('mouseover', '#featured-image-one', function () {
    $hoverText.show();
});
$('body').on('mouseout', '#featured-image-one', function () {
    $hoverText.hide();
});
```

Comment: acjohnson55, thank you! You also provided some insight as to the proper usage of jQuery's .on() event handler, which I think I was using incorrectly on my initial attempt.

Comment: Yeah, `on` is a bit tricky at first.  You can hook it directly to the element you want instead of `body`, but if that element is dynamic, you want to hook it to something that will exist at load time, otherwise you will have to hook that element after it is loaded.  Technically, you should hook it to the deepest preexisting ancestor of the element whose event you want to catch to make the selector search as efficient as possible.  I just picked `body` as the shallowest common denominator.